# Nginx - open socket left in connection and worker_connections are not enough

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, ssl

I have app in node.js.
But i have 100 users and get this error:

```
first: open socket left in connection 
second: worker_connections are not enough
```

and broswer return 500 error.

Here is my domain.conf:

```
server {
    server_name xxx.com;

    root /var/www/web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    location / {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7777;

    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxx.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot

    }
```

Comment: Please do not repost the same question. Instead, edit your existing question.